# Unable to start test system 'slim': java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, unix, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I am using FitNesse slim on a UNIX server for database testing, using this as my base project: https://github.com/markfink/dbslim

I have built the dbslim .jar using maven in eclipse locally and copied it onto a UNIX servers lib folder (at /var/tmp/fitnesse/lib) which already contains all the needed dependencies. I run the `#!/bin/ksh /var/java/1.7.0_51/bin/java -jar lib/fitnesse-standalone.jar &` 
command from /var/tmp, starting FitNesse on port 80. I navigate to MyServer:80 on my browser and try to run a test page. I'm greeted with

`Unable to start test system 'slim': java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": error=2, No such file or directory` when I have fixture code and when I have none I receive

`Could not complete testing: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": error=2, No such file or directory`

Can someone explain how FitNesse cannot find the java version to run?

Comment: Do you have `java` in your path?

Comment: Yes, here is my fixture class `!path /var/java/1.7.0_51/bin/java
!path /var/tmp/fitnesse/lib/*.jar


!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

|import  |
|services|
|slim    |`

Comment: I talking about  environment variable `path`. If you just type `java -version` does it run properly?

Comment: I'm running FitNesse from a UNIX server which has a java version (/var/java/1.7.0_51/bin/java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `/var/java/1.7.0_51/bin` to the PATH environment variable before starting FitNesse.

Try starting FitNesse using `PATH="$PATH:/var/java/1.7.0_51/bin" && java -jar lib/fitnesse-standalone.jar &`

Comment: Worked right away once I added the java path, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please add the JDK path as bellow to your JDK Path in Jenkins-

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Please format your code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks